# Why PhpStorm can not show xml objects content during debugging with PhpUnit?

Tags: php, xml, debugging, phpunit, phpstorm

My PhpStorm can show what is inside every variable which i am using during debugging, except SimpleXMLElement. It is shown below:

[image]

I have external environment on my local vagrant machine.

Comment: I may only suggest to check these tickets: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30656 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LazyOne had done great job. With his help i solved my problem. It was problem with Xdebug version. All you need to do is:
1. Uninstalling Your xdebug module with this command:

`sudo pecl uninstall xdebug`

2. Install specific version using command:

`sudo pecl install xdebug-2.3.2`

After that all should work well.